# Can't access wordpress admin page link

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wp-admin, wordpress-login

I use the plugin "Change WP admin login" to change the path to the admin page, no problem until I want to move the wordpress website from the live server to localhost, I can't access the admin page by path changed by plugin, localhost/website/wp-admin <= this path also not working, give me solution, thanks.

Give me solutions, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on source [page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-wp-admin-login/#i%20can%27t%20log%20in%3F):

In case you forgot the login URL or for any other reason you can’t log in on the website, you will need to delete the plugin via SFT/FTP or cPanel on your hosting.

Path for the plugin folder:
/wp-content/plugins/change-wp-admin-login

Advanced users:
Go to your MySQL database and look for the value of rwl_page in the options table

Advanced users (multisite):
Go to your MySQL database and look for the rwl_page option will be in the site meta table or options table.